# Combing Select-object and Where-object

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a script

```
 Get-NSLBVirtualServer | Select-Object name, curstate, statechangetimesec |Where {$_.curstate -is "DOWN"}
```

This unfortunately produces the following error

Cannot convert the "DOWN" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
At line:1 char:82

- ... ct name, curstate, statechangetimesec | Where-object {$_.curstate -is "DOWN"}

However it works fine if I remove the | where-object {$_.curstate -is "DOWN"}

```
Get-NSLBVirtualServer | Select-Object name, curstate, statechangetimesec

name                               curstate       statechangetimesec      
----                               --------       ------------------      
vip.A                               DOWN           Fri Aug 26 12:26:49 2022
vip.B                               UP             Tue Jan 31 02:27:28 2023
vip.c                               UP             Wed Nov 23 10:29:25 2022
vip.d                               DOWN           Mon Jul 25 22:39:39 2022
vip.e                               DOWN           Fri May 20 21:00:35 2022
```

What I would like to do is only display the data where the curstate is DOWN.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please. I tried googling and using the help-where-object and thought I had it correct however I can not find an example of select-object and where-object being used together.

Comment: Try the comparison with `-eq` ... not `-is`  ... here you can read more [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you Olaf that worked a treat, I saw -eq but didn't consider using it.

Comment: -is is a type test `1 -is 'int'`